# UIKit trackpad: while click + drag in progress, detect additional touch-less drag

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui, uikit

IMMEDIATE GOAL: during a trackpad click + drag gesture, detect and react to an additional (no-click) trackpad drag / pan gesture.

PROBLEM: UIKit seems to ignore the additional, no-click two-finger pan on trackpad so long as the first trackpad click + drag is ongoing.

BIG PICTURE UX: a “click + drag” and a “click + drag + another pan” should have different behavior.

EXAMPLE: the desired behavior is similar to Figma: while a component’s name is grabbed, a pan gesture from an additional two fingers will cause the background (rather than the component) to move around.

CURRENTLY:

- just click + drag on trackpad: a gesture with touches = 1 fires
- just pan / drag (no click) on trackpad: a gesture with touches = 0 fires
- during a click + drag, adding another pan/drag: the same gesture as from the touches = 1 fires

WHAT I’VE TRIED:

- looking at touches and locations of the various gesture recognizers
- looking at `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`’s delegate methods like `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)`
- `minTouches = 1` on one trackpad UIKit gesture recognizer (i.e. the click+drag) and `maxTouches = 0` for the other (i.e. the no-click drag)
- (code not shared here): an injectable UIKit wrapper that sits over the entire view and also listens for trackpad gestures (same results as above)

CODE:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct StackOverflowUIKitView: View {
    var nodeView: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.red.opacity(0.9))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .overlay(TrackpadUIKitGesture(name: "Node"))
            .position(x: 500, y: 400)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack { nodeView }
            .border(.purple, width: 18)
            .background(TrackpadUIKitGesture(name: "Graph"))
    }
}

struct TrackpadUIKitGesture: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let name: String

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        let delegate = context.coordinator

        let trackpadPan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(
            target: delegate,
            action: #selector(delegate.trackpadPanInView))
        trackpadPan.allowedScrollTypesMask = [.continuous, .discrete]
        trackpadPan.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirectPointer.rawValue)]
        trackpadPan.delegate = delegate
        vc.view.addGestureRecognizer(trackpadPan)

        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController,
                                context: Context) { }

    func makeCoordinator() -> TrackpadDelegate {
        TrackpadDelegate(name: name)
    }
}

class TrackpadDelegate: NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                           shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        true
    }

    @objc func trackpadPanInView(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let view = gestureRecognizer.view else {
            fatalError("\(name) error: no view.")
        }

        let touches = gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches
        let state = gestureRecognizer.state

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: view).toCGSize
        let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)

        log("\(name): touches: \(touches)")
        log("\(name): state: \(state)")
        log("\(name): translation: \(translation)")
        log("\(name): location: \(location)")

        if touches > 1 {
            let touch0 = gestureRecognizer.location(ofTouch: 0, in: view)
            log("\(name): touch0: \(touch0)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have to handle this by using the touche  methods.